# pyodbc error: using django in docker container

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, docker, pyodbc

I am using a docker container running django application.

T get the below error whenever I try to run function that manipulates data on 2 separate databases:

> error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

This is the function I run

```
def preStepBtn3(request):
    sourcePE = request.GET.get('sourcePE')
    targetPE = request.GET.get('targetPE')
    inputFTID = request.session['username']
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now()
    step_name = "preStepBtn3"
    table_name = "null"
    Action_taken = "change router status to MIG"
    MassivePortalSessionID = request.session['MassivePortalSessionID']

    try:
        with connections['DataAdmin'].cursor() as cursor:
            sql = """DECLARE @out nvarchar(max); exec DTA.mig_sop_ce_status2mig_django 0, %s, @param_out = @out OUTPUT; SELECT @out AS the_output; """
            params = [sourcePE]
            cursor.execute(sql, params)            
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            result = []
            result.append(rows)
            logDB_sql(MassivePortalSessionID, inputFTID, sourcePE, targetPE,
                      table_name, step_name, datetime_object, Action_taken)
            print("data inserted in log DB")
            while rows:
                print(rows)
                if cursor.nextset():
                    result.append(cursor.fetchall())
                else:
                    print(result)
                    return JsonResponse(result,  safe=False)
    except Exception as ex:
        error = ex
        print(error)
        context = {'text': error}
        logDB_sql(MassivePortalSessionID, inputFTID, sourcePE, targetPE,
                  table_name, step_name, datetime_object, Action_taken)
        print("data inserted in log DB during exception")
        return render(request, 'posts/textArea.html', context)
```

Whenever I remove the logDB_sql it works perfectly.
This is code for logDB_sql

```
def logDB_sql(MassivePortalSessionID, inputFTID, sourcePE, targetPE, table_name, step_name, datetime_object, Action_taken):
    params = [MassivePortalSessionID, inputFTID, sourcePE, targetPE,
              table_name, step_name, datetime_object, Action_taken]
    print(targetPE)
    print(sourcePE)
    print(MassivePortalSessionID)
    print(inputFTID)
    if sourcePE != None and MassivePortalSessionID != None and targetPE != None and inputFTID != None:
        sql = " insert into MASSIVE_MIGRATION_PORTAL_LOGS values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s )"
        print(sql)
        print(params)
        with connections['logDB'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, params)
            cursor.close()
            print("data inserted")
```

This is connection info in settings.py. note that they are different hosts

```
    'logDB': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'log_db',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': 'password1',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'timeout': 1000,
        }

    },

    'DataAdmin': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'another_db',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'USER': 'user1,
        'PASSWORD': 'password1',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'timeout': 1000,
        }
    },

}
```

And this is the error message

```
 File "/app/posts/views.py", line 387, in preStepBtn2
    table_name, step_name, datetime_object, Action_taken)
  File "/app/posts/views.py", line 90, in logDB_sql
    with connections['logDB'].cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 307, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have tried it locally on my windows machine and it works without any issues, not sure why it is failing when i move it to docker container.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? Older versions of SQL Server (e.g.: 2008 R2) don't support the TLS 1.2 protocol required by modern client drivers, especially if they're using OpenSSL. You can manually confirm server support by way of `openssl s_client --host <YourServerIP> --port 1433` with the `-tls1`, `-tls1_1`, `-tls1_2` and `-tls1_3` switches.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i have tried and got:
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 188 bytes
Verification: OK
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
Protocol : TLSv1.2
Cipher: 0000
Session-ID:
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key:
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint:None
SRP username:None
Start Time:1586453378
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
Extended master secret: no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by updating the `openssl.cnf` file in `/etc/ssl/`

Changed `MinProtocol = TLSv1.2` to `MinProtocol = TLSv1.0`  & `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` to `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`

Hope this helps.